# Visual C++ 2010 error. Can't Find program.exe when running

Tags: c++

This is the message I get

> Unable to start program C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EULER'S Fixed\Debug\EULER'S Fixed.exe
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Here is the Build Output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: EULER'S Fixed, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\adicpluplu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EULER'S Fixed\Debug\Debug\EULER'S Fixed.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Pay attention to compilers output!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to define main:

```
int main()
{
     //..
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're close. If memory serves right, he's picked the wrong project type - *Windows project* instead of *console* or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You get that message when you fail to save all before the first compile.

I consider it to be a defect in 2010.  Creating a new project, or adding files to a project or deleting files from a project don't actually save.  You have to manually save before they are really there.

Answer (score 0):

Select the properties for the file in which main is defined and make sure "item type" under "General" (under Configuration Properties) is set to "c/c++ compiler"